# in angular-nvd3 how to Invert donut Chart

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

is there a way to invert angular nvd3 [donut chart](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/donutChart) (`pieChart` with `donut: true,`)?
that will draw the chart in the inverted sense which is the second part of the donut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under pie options change the `startAngle` to:

```
function (d) { return d.startAngle/2 - (3 * Math.PI / 2) }
```

And `endAngle` to:

```
function (d) { return d.endAngle/2 - (3 * Math.PI / 2) }
```